# How to fetch data with transfer param from PHP script to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http-get

I don't know how to fetch data by a GET-request with one parameter to a PHP-script and return an array with one or more objects back to the angularjs script. Following, I defined:

angular controller:

```
vm.getUserById = getUserById;
function getUserById(userid) {
   var param = {
      id: userid
   };

   var config = {
      params: param
   };

   $http.get('data/getuser.php', config).then(
      function (res) { vm.data = res.data; },
      function (err) { console.log('Error: ', err); });
}
```

php script:

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data->id); //line 26

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . $userid . "";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$output = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) //line 34
{
    $output[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

When I send a GET-request, the URL is sending correctly ==> `http://localhost/myapp/data/getuser.php?id=7`

But it doesn't send an object back to the frontend.

I'm getting the following message:
Trying to get property of non-object in **...\myapp\data\getuser.php** on line **26**

**Warning**:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in **...\myapp\data\getuser.php** on line **34**
[]

Do I need a correct address with param in the method `file_get_contents("php://input")`? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `print_r($data)`

Comment: `json_decode` with second parameter `true` decodes to __array__, not __object__.

Comment: @u_mulder I get the same error message.

Comment: Once again - what shows `print_r($data)`? What shows `file_get_contents("php://input")`?

Comment: @u_mulder It returns nothing.